# Not able to do SSL connection in weblogic server

Tags: ssl, jakarta-mail, weblogic12c

I am trying to run a email sending code in weblogic server and getting below exception.

But if I run the standalone jar outside the weblogic on the same linux machine, it works fine. It looks like the SSL connection is not happening.

Please help me to solve this.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Method not implemented
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.provider.FarmKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(FarmKeyStoreSpi.java:545)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getTrustManagers(SSLContextImpl.java:771)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:748)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:913)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:289)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
```

I see below logs as well when debug for SSL is enabled.

```
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
--other cipher suites as well
Inaccessible trust store: kss://system/trust
trustStore is: /ade_autofs/gd29_3rdparty/nfsdo_generic/JDK8/MAIN/LINUX.X64/190708.1.8.0.221.B11/jdk8/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is: kss
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Mon Jul 08 23:37:35 PDT 2019
Reload the trust store
SunX509: skip default keystore: java.io.IOException: Method not implemented
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Finalizer, called close()
```

Answer (score 2):

kss(KeyStore Service) is available only in WebLogic JRF domains.  The JDK KeyStore engine should not load kss://system/trust unless it's configured somewhere.  Check your WebLogic server startup system properties to see if -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=kss://system/trust is configured.  If you don't mean to use KSS, remove that system property.

Figuring out the root cause of this issue might require you providing your WebLogic server configurations.  Contact Oracle Support if you need further help.